# Testing if two lists are equal regardless of the order of the objects in it

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Is there a way to check if two lists are equal, **depending on the values in it but regardless of their order**.

for example:

`[3,4,5] == [5,3,4]` will be: `true`

You can of course sort the 2 lists and then compare them, the question is whether it is possible to check if lists are equal using their values, without sorting them

Comment: If the values are all hashable, then keeping the two collections as sets instead of lists would be the simplest answer.  (There might be some issues if duplicate values are possible.)

Comment: Sets will do for most applications but note that sets can't hold the same element more than once.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony The question was without sort

Comment: @Arica. Ooops! :)

Comment: Having committed the ultimate blooper by not reading the entire question, I'm left with the question, Why? What is the scenario, where using `sort` is not applicable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use **Counter** from **collections**

```
Counter(listA) == Counter(listB)
```

or if you want to sort them

```
sorted(listA) == sorted(listB)
```

Comment: `Counter(listA) == Counter(listB)` looks great!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to sort, then compare the quantities of the present elements of each in the form of a dictionary using Counter from python's collections library.

```
from collections import Counter

def check_equal_without_sort(arr1, arr2):
    return Counter(arr1) == Counter(arr2)

arr1 = [3,4,5]
arr2 = [5,3,4]
print(check_equal_without_sort(arr1,arr2))
```